# Select rows with maximum value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, max

Through this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column) we can get the rows with maximum value as

```
select yt1.*
from yourtable yt1
left outer join yourtable yt2
on (yt1.id = yt2.id and yt1.rev < yt2.rev)
where yt2.id is null;
```

and assume the above result gives

```
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| id   | rev   | content                              |
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
| 1    | 3     | 15                                   |
| 2    | 1     | 18                                   |
| 4    | 2     | 14                                   |
+------+-------+--------------------------------------+
```

I am joining another table which has the above `id` as `primary key`

```
 +------+-------+-------------+
 | id   | myId  | type        |
 +------+-------+-------------+
 | 1    | 1     | 1           |
 | 2    | 1     | 1           |
 | 3    | 2     | 1           |
 | 4    | 2     | 1           |
 +------+-------+-------------+
```

as

```
  select bt.myId, yt1.*
        from baseTable bt 
        inner join yourtable yt1 (on bt.id=yt1.id)
        left outer join yourtable yt2
        on (yt1.id = yt2.id and yt1.rev < yt2.rev)
        where yt2.id is null;
```

and the join gives the result as

```
+------+------+-------+-----------------------+
| myId | id   | rev   | content               |
+------+------+-------+-----------------------+
| 1    | 1    | 3     | 15                    |
| 1    | 2    | 1     | 18                    |
| 2    | 4    | 2     | 14                    |
+------+------+-------+-----------------------+
```

Now how can I get the rows with max of content value based on `myId`. ie, the final output will be the sets `[1,2,1,18]` and `[2,4,2,14]`. It can be achieved by creating view of first result and again doing the same type of query for the view too. Is there any methods without view???

Comment: Your contents are int or string ? And also give sample data from both tables with desired result.

Comment: Back in 2011, this was a viable solution. For sentimental reasons it's still my favourite, but times have moved on. Take a look at the uncorellated subquery solution in the manual. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty content is int and question is updated.